# I see my URL but I can't find the page in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, url

I'm using wordpress and my page has the URL http://proservicescontractors.com/services/

But when I go to the page in my dashboard with the above URL, any change I make does not show on the front end. I tried simply duplicating my content and that change did not show on the front end.

Not sure what to do, this has me completely baffled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that it's actually a page? It looks like a custom post type archive to me.

Comment: I'm not certain...

Ok but would the dashboard "Page" have the same URL http://proservicescontractors.com/services/ as the page being displayed? And where would I find and edit it if it is a custom post type archive?

Comment: the template being used is the archive-service.php Can I edit it in Dashboard, not using the editor? 

I'm trying to change the meta title. I can't do it on the aforementioned Page. I looked in the archive-service.php code and I couldn't find anything showing how the meta title gets pulled in.

Comment: If all you're trying to achieve is to change the meta title tag, the method varied according to the theme you're using, and since you're using a premium theme, I can't tell you *exactly* how to go about this. If your theme is [declaring support for title-tag,](http://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-1-to-introduce-theme-support-for-the-title-tag) the easiest option would be to look for a plugin that lets you customise the title. Older themes might use wp_title() instead, in which case you can look into [apply a filter to amend it as require.](https://tommcfarlin.com/filter-wp-title/).

Comment: Typically you can't edit archive templates in the admin area; they are more like containers that simple display multiple posts, as opposed to having their own content. The page you're seeing in the admin area is probably a regular page that has the same name ('services'). When you go to that particular URL, WordPress is prioritising the archive over the page. 
What exactly are you trying to edit?

Comment: Yes, There is a custom post type called "Services". It contains all the services I entered. How do I know the page or post they are feeding into?

Comment: Be default, they're not actually loaded into a page *per se*; archives are distinct from pages and don't show up in the admin. I've left you an answer below with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're custom post types, by default, they're not actually loaded into a page *per se.* You should [read up on WordPress's template hierarchy.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) To give you a rough idea of what's happening:

1. WP looks at your URL, and since it recognises it as a custom post type archive, it will look for a template to use...
2. It will first look for `archive-$post_type.php`, or in your case, `archive-services.php`
3. If it can't find that, it will look for `archive.php`
4. If it can't find that, it will use `index.php`

**The important thing to note is that archive pages don't actually show up in the admin area, since they simply gather up and display custom posts, so there's nothing for you to edit.**

Now, if you really want to edit some content on the Services archive, you have two options:

#### Edit archive-services.php in a text editor.

This is the quick and dirty option; the downside is that it defies the point of a CMS.

#### Create a page template with it's own loop

Create a new page template called `page-services.php` and insert a loop in there to display your custom posts. To get you started:

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php // The main loop  
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
    }
} else {
    echo 'No posts';
}
?>

<?php // Now for the services loop
// WP_Query arguments
// For additional options, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters
$args = array (
    'post_type' => array( 'services' ),
);

// The Query itself
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Do something with the post
        // In your case look at archive-services.php and see what
        // that template does inside the loop
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
// Don't forget this, it's important
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

You should then be able to apply that page template to your Services page; it should then display your posts below the page content. One thing to look out for is that **WordPress will continue to load `archive-services.php` whenever you go to `http://proservicescontractors.com/services/`.** While there are ways around this, the easiest fix would be to simply give your new page a different url, such as `http://proservicescontractors.com/all-services/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I'm using yoast and I wanted to change the title and description. When you pointed out that it was a custom post type archive and not a page, I went back through yoast and found where I could change them under "Titles and Metas" > "Custom Post Type Archives" > "Services"